# Is there a way to get a speaker to talk using a TinyCLR program?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, frequency, speaker

I'm setting up a system using the GHI Electronics FEZ board(like an Arduino). I have created a way to send a frequency to a speaker and create a tone. Which allowed me to make music. Yet I can not figure out how to create tones that get a speaker to "talk" in a sense.

I have tried a text to speech nuget package that already exists yet it would not allow me to install it within the TinyCLR programming I am using.

C# using a Pulse Width Modulation controller I can control the desired frequency

```
public static PwmController fezPWM = PwmController.FromName(FEZ.PwmChannel.Controller3.Id);

static PwmChannel MusicSound = fezPWM.OpenChannel(FEZ.PwmChannel.Controller3.D11);
```

```
MusicSound.Start();
fezPWM.SetDesiredFrequency(F4s);
MusicSound.Stop();
```

The above part allows me to start and stop the sound and setting it to any desired frequency.

I expect it to use of desired frequencies in context to create a word. Yet all I get are different tones.

Comment: You are expecting what exactly "to create a word"?

Comment: @NetMage I am wanting to get the speaker to "talk" by using frequencies.

Comment: That would be the function of a text to speech library. You are kind of in the position of standing in front of a piano and saying you want to play the keys to make it talk.